# Is this sentence correct: "I want you to accept me just like I do to you"

Tags: grammar, verbs, ellipses

I know I can simply say it as "I want you to accept me just like I accept you". However, I want to know how can I say the same sentence using ellipsis.

Comment: *I do to you* would parallel *you accept to me*, but that is not how the sentence starts. Make the *to you* just *you*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin But neither *you accept to me* nor *I want you to accept to me like I do to you* are grammatical. The latter has **two** ungrammatical parts.